# Sizes and Naming of Launch Image for iPhone app in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, launch

What are ***sizes/naming*** of the ***launch images*** used for iPhone app in ***iOS***?

Answer (score 32):

> **Size Conventions**

iPhone3g      : 320 x 480

iPhone4/4s    : 640 x 960

iPhone5/5s    : 640 x 1136

iPhone6       : 750 x 1334

iPhone 6plus  : 1242 x 2208

> **Naming Conventions**

**For developers who don't wan't to use 'Asset Catalogs', they need to give specific names to launch images**

iPhone3g    : 'Default.png'

iPhone4/4s  : 'Default@2x.png'

iPhone5/5s  : 'Default-568h@2x.png'

iPhone6     : 'Default-667h@2x.png'

iPhone6plus :  'Default-736h@3x.png'

**For developers who would use 'Asset Catalogs', they don't need to give specific names to launch images**

Go to ***ProjectSetting -> General-> Under 'App Icons and Launch Images', select 'Use Asset Catalog'*** for 'Launch Image Source', and drag-drop the launch images for their OS version's/Orientations

Comment: As you mention in your question it's only for iOS 8 then why developers will not use Asset Catalogs. While it's pretty easy.... :/

Comment: Its upto the developer to use either of the two options, whichever of two he is comfortable with. I have explained two options here for the reference and also to ascertain the fact that there are two options for them.

Comment: And iPhone6plus Landscape?

Comment: I added only one image with size (Default-736h@3x.png, 1242 x 2208) to the asset catalog and used it in the launch xib file, and it runs in all screen sizes correctly, so not sure if creating these size variants necessary anymore.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199231/is-it-okay-to-leave-out-unnecessary-launch-images Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you use **images.xcassets** then you neither need to worry about the naming conventions nor to add those images into your project resource explicitly. Just drag and drop the appropriate size image to the appropriate box and XCode will do the rest.

And for image sizes please refers the [Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

[image]

Comment: +100 IMHO everyone should be using Asset Catalogs. It makes everything so much easier. And completely removes having to mess around with naming conventions.

Comment: Why does the "Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines" have a different naming convention... When it says "iPhone 5 @2x", which box do I drag it into? Can't any iPhone model have any iOS? what's the point of these guidelines if the two have no direct correlation?

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone 6:

**- 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait**

**- 1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape**

For iPhone 6 Plus:

**- 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait**

**- 2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape**

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199231/is-it-okay-to-leave-out-unnecessary-launch-images Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could consider using a using a launch storyboard or xib instead. Doing it this way only requires one that adapts to all sizes.

Note, this is works for iOS 8 only. If you use this in an app that also targets iOS 7, it will use the standard launch images when running on iOS 7 devices - but of course you only need 3.5 & 4 inch as the new larger iPhones don't support iOS 7!

See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) for more details.

Comment: The question title specifically refereed to IOS 8