# Launch screen and icon dimension issues and confusion in ios 7 and 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

After a lot of mess I am finally asking regarding the splash/launch screen confusion of iPhone and iPad. I visited many links but couldn't find an appropriate answer for that. I want the dimensions of iPhone and iPhone launch screens. Currently what I did for
for

**iPhone** 
Default-568h.png (320 x 568)

Default-568h@2x.png  (640 x 1136)
Default@2x.png  (640 x 960)

I used these three dimensions and they are working on all iPhones(from 4s to 6 plus). But there is a launch xib now provided. So whether this xib will run for the ios 7 or not?

Now if I use these two dimensions provided above for 4s, 5 and 5s, no doubt the **640 x 1136** is also applying in iphone 6 and 6 plus, but there may be some pixel blurring in launch of iphone 6 and 6 plus. Can anyone provide a generic way for launch screen for all devices (4s to 6 plus) with ios 7 and 8 support too.

**iPhone 6 and 6plus**

6+    (1242x2208)
6    (750x1334)
**Question**:-I know these dimensions are used for iphone 6 and 6+ but what will be the name of .png for these two devices just like we used Default-568h@2x.png etc for other devices if in case we don't use launch xib.

**iPad**
Default-Portrait~ipad.png (768 x 1024)
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (1536 x 2048)

Similarly for landscape
Default-Landscape~ipad.png (1024 x 768)
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png (2048 x 1536)

**Question**:-Is any other dimension is required with some other name?

**ICONS**
I used to to do entry in .plist with Icon Files and the dimensions are
29 x 29
40 x 40
50 x 50
56 x 56
57 x 57
58 x 58
60 x 60
72 x 72
76 x 76
80 x 80
100 x 100
114 x 114
120 x 120
144 x 144
152 x 152
512 x 512 for iTunesArtwork.png
1024 x 1024 for iTunesArtwork@2x.png

**Question**:- I listed almost all icon dimensions are but What will the the minimum number of icons that I need for all iphones (4s to 6 plus) and iPad? How many icon dimensions can I disgard from the above list. Any help will be appreciated in clearing the confusion.

Thanks

Comment: http://makeappicon.com/ios7icon# and http://makeappicon.com/ios8icon#

Comment: thanks..what about launch screens

Comment: Launch Screen http://stackoverflow.com/a/26754994/790842

Comment: hi thanks...will these names work for 6 and 6 plus?

Comment: If you are using Assets, you don't need to worry about file naming just use 2x, 3x etc, and drag and drop to asset, If your app supports iOS 7 and iOS8 both use asset only remove LaunchScreen.xib. If your app supports >= iOS8 use LaunchScreen.xib.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969533/how-to-handle-image-scale-on-all-the-available-iphone-resolutions

Comment: just want to know a generic solution whether app uses 7 or 8 or >=8. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Launch screen**

If you only support iOS 8.0+.

You only need **LaunchScreen.xib**.

Otherwise use **Images.xcassets**.

You can enable it in "Target > General > App Icons and Launch Images"

Select LaunchImage in Images.xcassets.

You can select support device and os in inspector.

Then XCode will tell you how many images you need.

You don't need to care image name just drag and drop it.

[image]

**Icons**

Use **Images.xcassets**.

Comment: but i want both for ios 7 and 8..generic sol..and I think that can be achieved my default.png etc naming conventions

Comment: i mean minimum number of icons?

Comment: Images.xcassets support 7 and 8. Icon is same as launch images. You can choose device and os in inspector.Xcode will show how much you need.